# Swift not sure if I am using segue the right way

Tags: ios, swift, segue

In my story board I have VC1>VC2>VC2>VC4

In order to go right back to VC1 from VC4 I have setup the function:

```
@IBAction func unwindToVcOne(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

Then adding that to my segue from the storyboard.
Everything works fine except that it shows up as an empty circle in my editor as its not connected:

[image]

It works, so is this something that I can ignore?

Comment: if its working properly you can safely ignore this, a quit and relaunch of Xcode may show this correctly.

Comment: @AnilVarghese thanks for your response, it always shows as empty even if I reload the project. But I will ignore it since it works

Comment: How does the unwindToVcOne method get called?  Is it really bound to something in Interface Builder, or do you only call it from other places in the code?  If you are calling the method from somewhere else, it may work, but it is not successfully bound to anything in IB.  Or are you setting up the binding in the code?

Comment: @wottle I was following this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

I ctrl-dragged form my close button to the exitUnwind, and when the popup shows up I select "unwindToVcOne"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the circle next to an unwind method always shows as empty as there isn't a fixed binding between the storyboard scene and the method the way that there is with an action method.

The `IBAction` lets Interface Builder know that there is a method it should be interested in; the method signature indicates that it is an unwind segue method.

The actual unwind method that is called is determined at runtime as describe in this [Apple Technical Note.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html)